# Oauth2 hash token on Auth Server

Tags: spring, spring-security, oauth, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I'm implementing an Auth server using Spring Security Oauth2. What I noticed is that when spring security saves the access token (using `JdbcTokenStore`) , the `OAuth2AccessToken` is serialized as which means the access token is self is saved as plain text. I have a couple questions about this.

1.) The token is never actually retrieved using the access token value. It is retrieved using a token id. Why is that?

2.) Is it Ok to hash this token since it is never retrieved using it's value?

3.) Do we actually need to generate the token id? Can we pass an extra information from the resource server to the authentication server to retrieve the token and validate it against the hash?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default Spring stores the token in plain text. If you make a request to get a token again in the same browser, you will notice that Spring will return the same token as long as it is still valid.

1) This is not entirely correct. On the resource server, the token is read from the header and a `PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken` is created. Through several steps the token value is used to create the `OAuth2Authentication`. The key is a intermediate step, but only after you have resolved the token to an `OAuth2AccessToken` (see `TokenStore.readAccessToken()`)

2) Personally I would hash the token before storing it in the database! This does however require you to implement/extend a TokenStore, since you need to override `TokenStore.storeAccessToken()` to save the hashed value, and `TokenStore.readAccessToken()` to hash the incoming token and find the hash in the database.

3) Typically the authentication server and resource server read the same database, and both ends up with a OAuth2Authentication identifying the user. If you want to hash, you just need to implement the store/read methods as described above.

I have implemented a solution like this with Spring Oauth2 1½ ago, so hashing tokens and refresh tokens is diffidently possible. In our case we ended up not using the resource server implementation from Spring Oauth2, because we get 20K requests every minute, and we wanted to delay resolving the token until the request has been validated, and use several layers of caching to avoid hitting the database on every request.

Comment: In your solution, did you use one way hashing? If so, how did you retrieve the token?

Comment: Hashing is always one way, the principle is the same as normal password hashing. You give the client the unhashed token, when you receive the unhashed token in a request, you hash it and check if you have an unexpired hash with the same value. If you use a UUID as tokens, you don't need to use a salt, and you can get away with a single sha-256 hash, because the entropi of the UUID is much greater than regular passwords.